# Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS vs. Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: 12.04, unity, 12.10, gnome

should I pick Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS or 12.10 for my home machine?

I know that Ubuntu 12.04 is LTS but 12.10 is newer.

But what should I pick now?

Can I use Gnome 3 Shell (apt-get install gnome-shell) without any problems in Ubuntu or is it recommend to use Unity?

Greetings,
Majestro

Answer (score 1):

Since 12.04 is LTS. I'd suggest 12.04, if you're not willing to upgrade. 12.10(And 13.04 soon), I'd suggest those two if you'd want a more "fancy" feature-updated machine.

New features in 12.10 is listed here: http://www.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/whats-new - And if you can go without those, I'd install 12.04.

Answer (score 1):

I moved from 12.04 64bit to 12.1064bit on my desktop machine and run 12.04Lts on my servers.

From a technical aspect?..  I don't have enough reliable technical knowledge to offer any advice that would be constructive.

From a usability perspective.  12.10 seems smoother and a little sharper.  It's video is more polished.  On my 64bit 3.0ghz 8gb ram Dell 780 desktop it's beautifully smooth.

The 12.04 seemed a little more stable, with the qualifier that I play a little and have destroyed more installs than I can remember :)

I'm using Unity at home and xcfe at work after going through KDE, LXDE (this is worth having a look at with lower than 4gb ram machines) and Gnome.

You can install gnome desktop on any of the Ubuntu flavours, but a direct download and install is more convenient and a little tighter integrated. KUbuntu(kde), XUbuntu(Xfce) LUbuntu(Lxde).

Can I  suggest you download a few and make some bootable cd's, give 'em a whirl and see what you think?  If your still unsure you can install different desktop environments through out the different Ubuntu flavours.

I've warmed to Unity, but as it turns out with customisations all over the place, it now looks and behaves more like a mac (after spending 20 years on windows), go figure! :)

Always remember,  Linux can't be judged as an "operating system" in the same vane windows is. It's actually a usability experience.  You can do what ever your imagination can conjure, including customising the environment you work to an unrecognisable point.

Linux enables you to run a $50 Rasberry Pi as a home media server, or run a Particle Accelerator buried under Switzerland and go hunting for Higgs particles :)  I'd be guessing you and I somewhere between :)  Which gives us enormous choice.

Go Play!

Quick tip!  Run at least 2 partitions!  one as a home partition and one for boot.

After trashing so many installs (Entirely my fault, nothing to do with Ubuntu or Linux. I poke screw drivers into light sockets :) )  Having your /home directory on a separate partition is a god send! :)  And do backups!  Damn it!

Answer (score 0):

I think it all depends on when you will upgrade your reinstall your distribution again. If you want it to last for a while and don't really care about having the lastest versions of every piece of sotfware, you should go with 12.04. While 12.10 has some awesome features like the new Nautilus or Gnome 3.6, it may be a little buggier (though it all depends on you computer). You can use Gnome with either of them, and it works very well, but in 12.04 you only get Gnome 3.4, though. Kernel-wise, they use 3.5, so there is not much difference between the distributions.

In my case, I was perfectly happy with 12.04, and only installed 12.10 to try Gnome Shell 3.6 and really like the new Nautilus.

So, in the end, I would suggest 12.10, but you will be happy with wichever you choose.